# Linked Informix table in MS SQL Server ignoring criteria?

Tags: sql-server, informix, linked-tables

I’m having a problem with a linked Informix table in MS SQL Server 2008r2. When I query this table, it seems to ignore some of the criteria I’m passing to it but not others. For example if I put a condition on the rowdate field the remote query part of the execution plan does not show any WHERE clause but if I put criteria on another field such as ACD it does show.

It seems it does not pass any criteria on the rowdate field but does on all others.

I know the field is indexed on the Informix side. If it helps the table I’m linking is from Avaya CMS and it is linked via the OpenLink ODBC driver.

EDIT:

As far as I know it is Informix Dynamic Server 2000 and it is on Solaris. The column comes up as a DATE data type which is correct. I have tried passing the criteria as ‘2010-08-03 00:00:00’, ‘2010-08-03’, CONVERT(date,’2010-08-03’) and a few more variations. When the data is returned to SQL server it is in the format yyyy-mm-dd.

When I view the execution plan I can see the remote query with all the other criteria followed by a filter for only the rowdate field.

I know that rowdate is indexed and that the driver does normally communicate that information as we use it in other applications (Business objects and MS Access) and they don’t have a problem

Comment: Which version of Informix on which platform? What is the type of 'rowdate'? At a guess, it is DATE but it could be one of the variants of DATETIME such as DATETIME YEAR TO DAY or DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND. Are any other columns of the same type treated the same way by the drivers? **Superficially** this sounds like a problem on the 'client' side; that is, if the driver does not send the criterion, the server cannot use it. You might want to explore how to get SET EXPLAIN ON executed so that you can see what the Informix DBMS sees as the SQL for comparison with what you think it should be seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out but it is the strangest thing ever. I went down the route of passing the date in different formats. My default is to use the normal YYYY-MM-DD that of course did not work so I tried YYYY-MMM-DD, still nothing. After going through LOTS of combinations I found one that works Mmm-DD-YY and it has to be exactly that! SEP-21-2010 wont work but Sep-21-2010.

I wonder if this is just a strange hang up from Informix or something in the driver, anyway it works.

On a side note has anyone noticed how strange it is that people from the America write the date month, day year? Stop and think about it for a second, do you say the number 2410 as “Four hundred, ten, two thousand”? The best part about it is try asking yourself this, what day is American independence day? Most Americans say “That’s easy you limey person it is the 4th of July” hmmmm day month (year), the only date they say round the right way is the date they got their independence. I will leave it up to the SO community to see the irony in that

Answer (score 0):

Example query below:

```
select *
from OPENQUERY (AVAYA, 'select row_date,starttime,intrvl,acd from root.hagent where
row_date = ''NOV-22-2012'' and acd = 1 and split = 1 and starttime = 1900')
```

By the way I managed to extract accurate data via both MMM-DD-YYYY and Mmm-DD-YYYY.